# Unity Terrain Tools plants trees sideways

Tags: unity, terrain, tree

[image]

My tree is clearly straight, but painting trees result in sideways ones.
What can cause this?

Tree is straight when placed manually as a prefab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like its a [handedness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule) issue, in 3d graphics the choice of which axis is called what is kind of arbitrary (to a point) and there are a couple of different common standards.

Unity uses the left-handed, Y up, but other software, particularly 3d modeling software like blender, use right-handed, Y or Z up.

[Freya Holmér](https://twitter.com/FreyaHolmer) made this really great reference image

[image: Handedness explanation]

Realistically the fix is just to transform your model by rotating it, or scaling one dimension by -1, either in unity or in some 3d modeling software, until it looks correct.

Comment: Scaling by -1 alone won't fix the issue in the question, but rotating the z axis to point along y (or something along those lines) should work.